# How to handle a reply for long-running REST request?

Tags: c#, rest

**Background:** We have import-functions that can take anywhere from a few seconds to 1-2 hours to run depending on the file being imported. We want to expose a new way of triggering imports, via a REST request.

Ideally the REST service would be called, trigger the import and reply with a result when done. My question is: since it can take up to two hours to run, is it possible to reply or will the request timeout for the caller? Is there a better way for this kind of operation?

Comment: A common pattern for this is to start the process on the server, report an identifier to the client and let the client periodically check on the status of the process. If you want, you could event implement some kind of push notification to your application.

Comment: ASP.NET already provides signaling through SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

What I use in these cases is an asynchronous operation that returns no result (void function result in case of c# Web API), then send the result asynchronously using a message queue.

E.g.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("update")]
public void Update()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => this.engine.Update());
    task.ContinueWith(t => publish(t, "Update()"));
}
```

Comment: 1) SignalR already provides client notifications using long polling, web sockets or infinite frames. 2) You *shouldn't* use fire-and-forget tasks for this as IIS can kill them at any time if it doesn't know about them. At the very least, you need to register them. A 2 hour job though simply shouldn't be handled by IIS as it hurts scaleability

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 1) The OP didn't mention he is using SignalR and the messaging could be implemented in different ways (e.g. SignalR, Message Queue), depending on his requirements (which he did not post). 2) a 2 hour job isn't the best practice, however, you can prevent from recycling daily and on idle, thus preventing it from being killed. A better practice would be to split the job into small jobs and resume them.